# Cycling Slicing in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, slice

I've come up with this question while trying to apply a Cesar Cipher to a matrix with different shift values for each row, i.e. given a matrix `X`

```
array([[1, 0, 8],
   [5, 1, 4],
   [2, 1, 1]])
```

with shift values of `S = array([0, 1, 1])`, the output needs to be

```
array([[1, 0, 8],
   [1, 4, 5],
   [1, 1, 2]])
```

This is easy to implement by the following code:

```
Y = []
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    if (S[i] > 0):
        Y.append( X[i,S[i]::].tolist() + X[i,:S[i]:].tolist() )
    else:
        Y.append(X[i,:].tolist())
Y = np.array(Y)
```

This is a left-cycle-shift. I wonder how to do this in a more efficient way using numpy arrays?

Update: This example applies the shift to the columns of a matrix. Suppose that we have a 3D array

```
array([[[8, 1, 8],
        [8, 6, 2],
        [5, 3, 7]],

       [[4, 1, 0],
        [5, 9, 5],
        [5, 1, 7]],

       [[9, 8, 6],
        [5, 1, 0],
        [5, 5, 4]]])
```

Then, the cyclic right shift of `S = array([0, 0, 1])` over the columns leads to

```
array([[[8, 1, 7],
        [8, 6, 8],
        [5, 3, 2]],

       [[4, 1, 7],
        [5, 9, 0],
        [5, 1, 5]],

       [[9, 8, 4],
        [5, 1, 6],
        [5, 5, 0]]])
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `[2,7,8]` for the last col in the 3D case and so on?

Comment: That might be the left shift.

Comment: Ah yeah, you mentioned right-shift there, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Use [`modulus`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.mod.html) to implement the cyclic pattern and get the new column indices and then simply use [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to extract the elements, giving us a vectorized solution, like so -

```
def cyclic_slice(X, S):
    m,n = X.shape
    idx = np.mod(np.arange(n) + S[:,None],n)
    return X[np.arange(m)[:,None], idx]
```

**Approach #2 :** We can also leverage the power of [`strides`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) for further speedup. The idea would be to concatenate the sliced off portion from the start and append it at the end, then create sliding windows of lengths same as the number of cols and finally index into the appropriate window numbers to get the same rolled over effect. The implementation would be like so -

```
def cyclic_slice_strided(X, S):
    X2 = np.column_stack((X,X[:,:-1]))
    s0,s1 = X2.strides
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided 

    m,n1 = X.shape
    n2 = X2.shape[1]
    X2_3D = strided(X2, shape=(m,n2-n1+1,n1), strides=(s0,s1,s1))
    return X2_3D[np.arange(len(S)),S]
```

Sample run -

```
In [34]: X
Out[34]: 
array([[1, 0, 8],
       [5, 1, 4],
       [2, 1, 1]])

In [35]: S
Out[35]: array([0, 1, 1])

In [36]: cyclic_slice(X, S)
Out[36]: 
array([[1, 0, 8],
       [1, 4, 5],
       [1, 1, 2]])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [75]: X = np.random.rand(10000,100)
    ...: S = np.random.randint(0,100,(10000))

# @Moses Koledoye's soln
In [76]: %%timeit
    ...: Y = []
    ...: for i, x in zip(S, X):
    ...:     Y.append(np.roll(x, -i))
10 loops, best of 3: 108 ms per loop

In [77]: %timeit cyclic_slice(X, S)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.1 ms per loop

In [78]: %timeit cyclic_slice_strided(X, S)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.3 ms per loop
```

---

**Adaption for `3D` case**

Adapting `approach #1` for the `3D` case, we would have -

```
shift = 'left'
axis = 1 # axis along which S is to be used (axis=1 for rows)
n = X.shape[axis]
if shift == 'left':
    Sa = S
else:
    Sa = -S    

# For rows
idx = np.mod(np.arange(n)[:,None] + Sa,n)
out = X[:,idx, np.arange(len(S))]

# For columns
idx = np.mod(Sa[:,None] + np.arange(n),n)
out = X[:,np.arange(len(S))[:,None], idx]

# For axis=0
idx = np.mod(np.arange(n)[:,None] + Sa,n)
out = X[idx, np.arange(len(S))]
```

There could be a way to have a generic solution for a generic `axis`, but I will keep it to this point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How this answer can be adopted to arrays of more dimensions? Like 3D arrays?

Comment: @AliShakiba So, what would be the length of `S`? Would it be same as the first axis or the second axis of `X`?

Comment: Yes. Suppose that we need to apply shifts to the right or the left, on any one of the dimensions.

Comment: @AliShakiba It's not clear. Could you add a sample case for a 3D array?

Comment: I've updated the question and added the example and fixed a typo.

Comment: thanks. that's great! and how can we change the shift for row to shift for columns? or even depth?

Comment: @AliShakiba Updated again.

Answer (score 1):

You could shift each row using `np.roll` and use the new rows to build the output array:

```
Y = []
for i, x in zip(S, X):
    Y.append(np.roll(x, -i))
print(np.array(Y))
```

---

```
array([[1, 0, 8],
       [1, 4, 5],
       [1, 1, 2]])
```